# How to make a floating div stick to the top

Tags: css, sass

I have 3 "boxes"/divs side by side with this class:

```
.roundedBox {
  float: left;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

Because the midle one is much taller then the other 2, I would like the other 2 to come down while we scroll down, so I tought to add this code/css class to the ones on the sides:

```
.stickTop {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

Doesn't seem to make any diference, what am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to do some tricks in there PLUS fix the structure of your HTML - because using "float" might become a problem with responsiveness.

**1st**, create `<div>` as the outer container, this will represent as the main "row" of your 3 column boxes (roundedBox, results, roundedBox). Class name it as "container". In your CSS, this one should have `display: flex; flex-direction: row;`

**2nd**, create another 3 `<div>` inside the `class="container"` as the column boxes. Class name each as "box-item". Add another class name on the first and third "roundedBox". In your CSS, "box-item" should have `width: 60%; position: relative;` and "roundedBox" should have `width: 20%;`

**3rd**, Inside of each `class="box-item"`, there will be another `<div class="inner-box-item">`. Because the tricks of floating boxes will start here. Add class names on the first and third "inner-box-item" with "box-float" and "box-left"/"box-right". In your CSS, "box-float" should have `position: fixed;`. This should float the left and right boxes upon scrolling the page. In your CSS again, add ".box-float" together with ".roundedBox" to have 20% width of the box.

Take note that every time you use `position: fixed;` in CSS, you have to always declare the item's width.

If you're asking why "inner-box-item" is necessary, you can experiment by removing it and just `position: fixed;` the ".box-item" instead. See what will happen there only if you have time.

See the HTML structure and CSS below, this should be easier for you to adjust the boxes in smaller devices too.

Structure:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.box-item {
  width: 60%;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.roundedBox, .box-float {
  width: 20%;
}
.inner-box-item {
  background: pink;
  height: 1000px;
}
.box-float {
  position: fixed;
  max-height: 50vh;
}
.box-left {
  left: 20px
}
.box-right {
  right: 20px
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="box-item roundedBox">
      <div class="inner-box-item box-float box-left">
        <p>A</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-item">
      <div class="inner-box-item">
        <p>B</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-item roundedBox">
      <div class="inner-box-item box-float box-right">
        <p>C</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but I was getting frustrated with getting the right sizes. I've posted my current solution. Would you please coment on it (as it seems you are more experience and more aware of future problems I might have if I try to optimize it for smaller screens).

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can check this approach below

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr min-content;
  position: relative;
}

.item-sticky {
  background: firebrick;
  padding: 1rem;
  height: 150px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 10px;
}

.item-long {
  background: orchid;
  padding: 1rem;
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item-sticky">
    Some content
  </div>
  <div class="item-long">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Earum, dolores.</div>
  <div class="item-sticky">Somecontent</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit what is going on in the .grid-container, I'm new with css and never heard of grid-template-columns or display: grid

Comment: I tried to add the grid containner to wrap my .roundedBox divs and got a weird result, sticky still doent work and messed the widths https://imgur.com/5qZKBi3
what should I pay attention too while implementing this?

Comment: The grid-container is just a wrapper that defines how the layout of children should be. You can check the MDN docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) for more clarity

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of playing around with the solutions of @Servesh Chaturvedi and @Sabrina L. (and a bit of dispair)

I think I found something that uses the principle of both using flex

```css
.roundedBox {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.grid-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 10px;
}

.item-long {
 background: orchid;
 height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="sticky roundedBox">Some content</div>
  <div class="roundedBox item-long ">Lorem ipsum dolor </div>
  <div class="sticky roundedBox">Somecontent</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is nice and should work! It should be easier for you to adjust this in smaller devices. By the way, since you are new to CSS, it would be better if you start coding in smaller devices before coding for bigger devices. This will give you shorter codes in CSS. [Bootstrap Framework](https://getbootstrap.com/) is one of the best example of this coding approach :) With Bootstrap, you don't have to always start from scratch, you only need to name your HTML tags with the right class names from bootstrap. It give you hassle-free coding in future ;) It saves my time when working on projects!